# Flatten a hierarchical JSON array using JQ

Tags: arrays, json, jq, flatten

Can anyone help me get the correct jq command to flatten the below example?  I've seen a few other posts and I'm hacking away at it but can't seem to get it.  I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Input:

```
[
    {
        "name": "level1",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "level2",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "level3-1",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "level3-2",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "displayName": "level1",
        "parent": ""
    },
    {
        "displayName": "level2",
        "parent": "level1"
    },
    {
        "displayName": "level3-1",
        "parent": "level2"
    },
    {
        "displayName": "level3-2",
        "parent": "level2"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a straightforward solution that does not involve a helper function and actually solves a more general problem.  It is based on the idea of beginning by adding a "parent" key to each child, and then using `..` to collect all the name/parent pairs.

So first consider:

```
[ walk(if type=="object" and has("children")
       then .name as $n | .children |= map(.parent = $n)
       else . end)
  | ..
  | select(type=="object" and has("name"))
  | {displayName: .name, parent}
]
```

This meets the requirements except that for the top-level (parentless) object, it produces a .parent value of `null`.  That would generally be more JSON-esque than "", but if the empty string is really required, one has simply to replace the last non-trivial line above by:

```
| {displayName: .name, parent: (.parent // "")}
```

Answer (score 1):

With a simple recursive function:

```
def f: .name as $parent | .children[] | {$parent, displayName: .name}, f;
[ {name: "", children: .} | f ]
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/3PlEhGQkex)</sup>